# Riesz representation theorem and integral equality in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm having trouble to understand how to tackle the following problem:

> Lets consider the Hilbert space $H = L^2(]0,1[)$. Show that there exist a unique $u \in L^2(]0,1[)$ such that:
> $$
>   \int_0^1
>     \left( \int_0^xu(t) \,\mathrm{d}t \right)
>     \left( \int_0^x v(t) \,\mathrm{d}t \right)
>   \,\mathrm{d}x
>   +
>   \int_0^1 u(x)v(x) \,\mathrm{d}x
>   =
>   \int_0^1 f(x) v(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \,,
> $$
> for $f \in H$ given.

I'm unsure how to even start, I know I will use Riesz representation theorem and that I need a linear form of $H$ but this integral equality is really disturbing me. Any hints or explanation would be appreciated.

Thank you !

Comment: Not sure if this works but maybe the LHS is a scalar product.

Comment: What is $f$ on the right side?

Comment: Oh yes sorry, $f$ is a given element of $H$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let
$$
B(u, v) = \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^x u\right)\left(\int_0^x v \right) + \int_0^1 uv
$$
and note that $B(u, u) \ge ||u||_{L^2}^2 \Rightarrow 
\sup_{||v|| = 1} |B(u, v)| \ge ||u||_{L^2}$, which when combined with the symmetry of $B$ implies $\sup_{||u|| = 1} |B(u, v)| > 0$. By [Lax-Milgram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babu%C5%A1ka%E2%80%93Lax%E2%80%93Milgram_theorem), given any $f \in L ^2$, we will have a unique $u_f \in L ^2$ s.t. $B(u_f, v) = \langle f, v \rangle$ for all $v \in L ^2$.

Comment: Thanks, they are some part i don't understand :  why does the symmetry of $B$ implies that, why is $B$ is continuous and also the Lax-Milgram usage i don't get why it gives that expression, i thought it would give $B(u_f,v)=f(u_f)$. Any details would be very nice of you :)

Comment: @vadkoslo The linear operator $Lf=\int_0^x f$ is bounded by Minkowski's inequality for integrals, thus $L$ is continuous. Cauchy-Schwartz implies the continuity of the inner product, and $B$ can be written as sums of compositions of these operations, so $B$ is continuous. One of the hypothesis of Lax-Milgram is that we have $\sup_{||u|| = 1} |B(u, v)| > 0$, but this follows from $\sup_{||v|| = 1} |B(u, v)| \ge ||u||$ by switching the arguments (symmetry). Finally, the conclusion of Lax-Milgram is $B(u_f, v) = f(v)$ for $f \in H^*$, but $f^*(v) = \langle f, v\rangle$ by Riesz Representation thm